# Call an Async action after updating the react state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to the `react js`. I have an action ,

```
export const updateActivePage = (activePage) => {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_ACTIVEPAGE,
    payload: activePage
  }
}
```

In my reducer ,

```
const initialState = {
 activePage: 1,
}
case UPDATE_ACTIVEPAGE:  {
      return {
        ...state,
        activePage: activePage
      }
    }
```

In my container,

```
handlePageChange = (pageNumber) => {
    this.props.updateActivePage(pageNumber);
    this.props.fetchUserJd(this.props.activePage);
  }
```

Now Here I want to call this   `this.props.fetchUserJd(this.props.activePage);` function only when the previous action is successfully updated that value. As this is not returning any promise.

Now, I have a solution that is a callback function.
But somehow `.then` is not avaliable in this as the first function is not returning any promise. any help will be helpful .

Comment: first of all what is `action.date` ?  you only have `payload: activePage` in your action

Comment: sorry that is my mistake

Comment: and it is better to do the `fetchUserJd` in `componentWillUpdate`

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps is now deprecated

Comment: [Creating a Promise around an old callback API
Section | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Creating_a_Promise_around_an_old_callback_API)

Comment: Actually I know that I can use this. then only thing is that is this the right way to do in react.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the folloowing: in your mapDispatchToProps fn return actions like this:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
         updateActivePage: (pageNumber) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                dispatch(actions.updateVisualState(pageNumber, resolve, reject));
            });
        }
};
```

in this case, you will be able to use then for your actions in the view:

```
this.props.updateActivePage(pageNumber).then(()=>{
  this.props.fetchUserJd(this.props.activePage);
})
```

You just need to choose the right place to resolve the promise.

Comment: How do I do this it in the action creator itself ?

Comment: Because I have lots of actions in my mapdispatchToProps